# SwiftUI Two observable objects in one View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm finding hard to understand how to link 2 observable objects. I have 2 lists and both are populated with @ObservedObjects, one has a Store Pattern (view model) and the other one connects to a model and modifies it. The array of observable objects in the document store, populates the some properties of a document in the List. I want to link the selection of a document with the properties appearing. My approach was to use a @Binding (the projected value of a @State property wrapper) to bind the Store with the other view model. The only way I get it to work was creating a @StateObject and the warning I received is "Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time."
I'll share you my code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var documentStore = PDFDocumentTaggerStore(named: "new store")
    @State private var selectedDocument:PDFDocumentTagger?
    
    init() {
        _selectedDocument = State(wrappedValue: documentStore.documents[0])
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            VStack {
                List(selection:$selectedDocument) {
                    ForEach(documentStore.documents) { document in
                        Text(documentStore.name(for:document))
                    }
                }
                HStack(alignment:.center) {
                    Button("Add") {
                        documentStore.addDocument(named: "1")
                    }
                    Button("Remove") {
                        print("Removed")
                    }
                }
                    List {
                        ForEach(selectedDocument!.regexWithLabels) { regexWithLabels in
                            Text("\(regexWithLabels.name!)")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the document store view model

```
import Foundation
import Combine

final class PDFDocumentTaggerStore:ObservableObject {
    
    let name:String
    
        func name(for document:PDFDocumentTagger) -> String {
            if documentNames[document] == nil {
                documentNames[document] = "Untitled"
            }
            return documentNames[document]!
        }
        
        func setName(_ name:String, for document:PDFDocumentTagger) {
            documentNames[document] = name
        }
        
        var documents:[PDFDocumentTagger] {
            documentNames.keys.sorted { documentNames[$0]! < documentNames[$1]! }
        }
        
        func addDocument(named name:String = "Untitled") {
            documentNames[PDFDocumentTagger()] = name
        }
        
        func removeDocuments(_ document: PDFDocumentTagger) {
            documentNames[document] = nil
        }
        
        @Published private var documentNames = [PDFDocumentTagger:String]()
        
        private var autosaveCancellable:AnyCancellable?
        
        init(named name: String = "InvoiceLabeler") {
            self.name = name
            let defaultsKey = "PDFDocumentTaggerStore.\(name)"
            documentNames = Dictionary(fromPropertyList: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: defaultsKey))
            autosaveCancellable = $documentNames.sink { names in
                print("document save")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(names.asPropertyList, forKey: defaultsKey)
            }
        
        }
    }

    extension Dictionary where Key == PDFDocumentTagger, Value == String {
        var asPropertyList:[String:String] {
            var uuidToName = [String:String]()
            for (key,value) in self {
                uuidToName[key.id.uuidString] = value
            }
            return uuidToName
        }
        
        init(fromPropertyList plist:Any?) {
            self.init()
            let uuidToName = plist as? [String:String] ?? [:]
            for uuid in uuidToName.keys {
                self[PDFDocumentTagger(id: UUID(uuidString: uuid))] = uuidToName[uuid]
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the document view model.

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import PDFKit


/// Store pattern a view model that represents a document store
final class PDFDocumentTagger:ObservableObject, Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    
    /// Conforming to the equatable protocol
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - lhs: left hand side of the expression
    ///   - rhs: right hand seid of the expression
    /// - Returns: a bool describing if one object is the same as the other
    static func == (lhs: PDFDocumentTagger, rhs: PDFDocumentTagger) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    /// Function to conform to the hashable protocol
    /// - Parameter hasher: hasher parameter`
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    @Published private var taggedDocument:TaggedDocument
    @Published private(set) var backgroundPDF:PDFDocument?
    
    let id:UUID
    
    private var autosaveCancellable:AnyCancellable?
    
    init(id:UUID? = nil) {
        self.id = id ?? UUID()
        let defaultsKey = "PDFDocumentTagger.\(self.id.uuidString)"
        taggedDocument = TaggedDocument(json: UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: defaultsKey)) ?? TaggedDocument()
        autosaveCancellable = $taggedDocument.sink(receiveValue: { (taggedDocument) in
            UserDefaults.standard.set(taggedDocument.json, forKey: defaultsKey)
        })
        
        createBackgroundPDF()
    }
    
    /// Function that creates a background pdf from scratch
    private func createBackgroundPDF() {
        backgroundPDF = nil
        guard let pdfURL = self.taggedDocument.url else { return }
        guard let pdfDoc = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL) else { return }
        self.backgroundPDF = pdfDoc
    }
    
    /// String that connects to the textfield every time it changes we add an annotation
    var regexString:String = "" {
        didSet {
            guard let pdfPage = backgroundPDF?.page(at: 0) else { return }
            performRegex(regex: regexString, on: pdfPage)
        }
    }
    
    /// Function that performs a regex search in the pdf string
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - regex: the regex string
    ///   - pdfPage: the current pdf page
    private func performRegex(regex:String, on pdfPage:PDFPage)  {
        guard let pdfString = pdfPage.string else { return }
        guard let safeRegex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: .caseInsensitive) else { return }
        let results = safeRegex.matches(in: pdfString, options: .withoutAnchoringBounds,
                                        range: NSRange(pdfString.utf16.startIndex..., in: pdfString))
        var badrange:NSRange?
        pdfPage.annotations.forEach { pdfPage.removeAnnotation($0) }
        results.forEach { result in
            guard let range = Range(result.range, in: pdfString) else {
                if badrange != nil {
                    badrange!.length += 1
                    if let range = Range(badrange!, in: pdfString) {
                        addAnnotationTo(pdfPage: pdfPage, from: pdfString, in: range)
                    }
                } else {
                    badrange = result.range
                }
                return
            }
            badrange = nil
            addAnnotationTo(pdfPage: pdfPage, from: pdfString, in: range)
        }
    }
    
    
    /// Function that adds a pdf annotation to the current pdf page
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - pdfPage: the current pdf page to which the annotation will be added
    ///   - pdfString: the strings of the pdf
    ///   - range: the range of the string in the pdf
    private func addAnnotationTo(pdfPage:PDFPage, from pdfString:String, in range:Range<String.Index>) {
        let bbox = pdfPage.selection(for: NSRange(range, in: pdfString))?.bounds(for: pdfPage)
        let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: bbox!, forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
        annotation.color = .yellow
        annotation.contents = String(pdfString[range])
        pdfPage.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
    
    
    //MARK:- Intents
    
    /// Modify the background url
    var backgroundURL:URL? {
        get { taggedDocument.url}
        set {
            taggedDocument.url = newValue
            createBackgroundPDF()
        }
    }
    
    //TODO: get the labels for the selected regex
    var regexWithLabels:Array<TaggedDocument.RegularExpressionWithResultingTags> {
        taggedDocument.regularExpressionWithResultingTags
    }
    
    //TODO: add labels to a stored regular expression
    
    //TODO: set the ground truth labels for a regular expression
    
    //TODO: remove the ground truth labels for a regular expression
    
    //TODO: set the file type of a pdf tagger document
    

}


// MARK: - Extention to attach bad ranges from objc to swift and be able to use them

public extension NSRange {
    private init(string: String, lowerBound: String.Index, upperBound: String.Index) {
        let utf16 = string.utf16
        
        let lowerBound = lowerBound.samePosition(in: utf16)
        let location = utf16.distance(from: utf16.startIndex, to: lowerBound!)
        let length = utf16.distance(from: lowerBound!, to: upperBound.samePosition(in: utf16)!)
        
        self.init(location: location, length: length)
    }
    
    init(range: Range<String.Index>, in string: String) {
        self.init(string: string, lowerBound: range.lowerBound, upperBound: range.upperBound)
    }
    
    init(range: ClosedRange<String.Index>, in string: String) {
        self.init(string: string, lowerBound: range.lowerBound, upperBound: range.upperBound)
    }
}
```

I tried to set it up using an environment object and couldn't. If anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you add the code for `PDFDocumentTaggerStore` as well? You probably just forgot to set it to `final`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply, I marked both classes as final but the warning persists. Any way I'll attach the code.

Comment: The warning seems pretty straightforward. `@StateObject private var documentStore = PDFDocumentTaggerStore(named: "new store")' will create a new store each time. Have you tried adding `public static let shared = PDFDocumentTagger()` to the document model and then setting your variable in ContentView as  an ObservedObject?

Comment: I don't quite understand the benefit? Could you please type it. Like in here

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem but the list is un selectable unless you embed it in a navigation view and use a navigation link inside of it.
The way I solved this was by replacing the @StateObject with an @ObservedObject and initializing it in the @main. So

```
@ObservedObject private var documentStore:PDFDocumentTaggerStore
@State private var selectedDocument:PDFDocumentTagger?

init(documentStore:PDFDocumentStore) {
    self.documentStore = documentStore
    _selectedDocument = State(wrappedValue:documentStore[0]
}
```

The warning is removed but I don't know why the first object is not selected, if I do it with a simple array it works, this way it does not (array of observable objects).